# Creating Azure Storage Container with Azurite aka Azure Local Storage: Name validation error

Tags: azure, azure-storage

From the screenshot below, you can see that I have Azurite/Azure Local Storage running and I'm trying to create a container for profile pictures, but I'm getting a name validation error message which doesn't make sense given the name I'm trying to use. Any Azurite experts out there know what I'm missing?

[image: Screenshot of powershell error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming convention for Blob Containers/Blobs/Metadata is described in details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata. No need for trial and error :).

Comment: I see. It would be helpful to include that in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Azure container names cannot contain uppercase letters. This is not very clear from the documentation, but I was able to figure it out with trial and error.